# Preventing DOM to be removed on closing of Fancy Box

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, dom

I amusing the fancybox plugin in wordpress with a form. So when a button is clicked the the form pops-up but when the pop-up is closed and the the button re-clicked, the form doesn't appear. Seems to me that modal the div (fancyboxID-1) that contains the form is removed from the DOM so when you then click the button again there is nothing for the modal to display.

Html:

```
<div style="display:none" class="fancybox-hidden"><div id="fancyboxID-1">
    <?php gravity_form(1, true, true, true, null, true, 3); ?>

    </div></div>

    <a href="#fancyboxID-1" class=" va-contact-link listing-contact-link cboxElement">Click here to enter your details</a>
```

CSS:

```
a.va-contact-link {
background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #FFFFFF, #EEEEEE) repeat scroll 0 0      transparent;
border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
color: #666666;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 11px;
font-style: italic;
font-weight: bold;
margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
padding: 5px 8px;
}
```

How can i solve this?

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: what is the fancybox type your are using here.

Comment: Create a fiddle please

Comment: @Anilkumar Im using the Easy Fancy Box Plugin

Comment: @user2725936 post your html code, creating the fiddle do better

Comment: @SarathSprakash I have included the Html code. I cant make a fiddle since i am using the fancy box plugin

Comment: @user2725936 where is your code now, better create a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

find the (Close popup) function using Firebug, look at the code.

there you'll know if it removes the form or not! if it's then change it to `fadeOut()` or `hide()` and stuff like this!

if it didn't work paste the code i'll check it!

Comment: Thanks, Ive edited the question to show the code. Still cant solve it

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the jQuery colorbox i was using. There to seemed to be a bug or something with that version. I updated it and the problem was fixed.

Thanks everyone.